# Lagrange multipliers and maximum entropy PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, lagrange-multiplier, entropy

This is a homework assignment, can someone provide some guidance (not a full solution):

There are three types of blocks: $A$, $B$, and $C$. All blocks look exactly the same, but they have a different weight: $w_A$, $w_B$, and $w_C$ respectively.

I have a total $n_T$ of blocks, but I don't know the amount of each block; I only know the total weight $w_T$. Use maximum entropy to obtain the joint probability.

**My Attempt**

I want to obtain $P(n_A, n_B, n_C)$ given the following constraints:
$$ n_A + n_B + n_C = n_T $$
$$ w_An_A + w_Bn_B + w_Cn_C = w_T$$
$$ \int_0^{n_T}\int_0^{n_T}\int_0^{n_T} P(n_A, n_B, n_C) \text{d}n_A\text{d}n_B\text{d}n_C = 1$$

I form the lagrangian function:
$$\mathcal{L} = -\int P(n_A, n_B, n_C)\ln P(n_A, n_B, n_C)\text{d}^3n - \lambda \left[\int P(n_A, n_B, n_C)\text{d}^3n - 1 \right] - \lambda_1\left[n_A + n_B + n_C - n_T\right] - \lambda_2\left[w_An_A + w_Bn_B + w_Cn_C - w_T\right]$$

But when I do the derivative w.r.t. $P$ I just end up with
$$P(n_A, n_B, n_C) = e^{-\lambda - 1}$$
And I think this is just telling be that my joint distribution is uniform. I don't think I am applying my constraints correctly. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing here but the Lagrange multiplier method always involves taking the gradient of the constraints with respect to the variables. In the case of your weight constraint you should get a vector $(w_A, w_B, w_C)$ as the constraint vector which is then multiplied by the lagrange multiplier. Then you solve for lambda.